# Non formatting tags outside html tag

Tags: html

I have a rather bizarre usecase.
I need a tag on top of a html document that will not be used in formatting but that will contain some information for the parsing entity to act upon (flags & data).
Normally comments are used for this:

```
<!-- foo = bar -->
<html>
etc.
```

Now we can strip 'foo' from the comment when the html is parsed and act upon its value 'bar'.

However I am now in the situation that one of the intermediate systems strips all comments from the html as it sends it along.

*So my question is*: What other tags can go outside of the html tag without breaking the html specs (too much)?

I know of the `<!doctype>` tag, but you cannot really put in data there without breaking something

NB:

- yes, I know this kind of signalling is ugly, but these are not my systems, I must provide such a flag.
- all comments are stripped
- js is not executed (yet) so we cant do it via the dom

Comment: meta tags? `<meta name="stripme" value="foo=bar" />`?

Comment: Could you not use a hidden div at the bottom of the body, that way it won't impact your seo rankings either as I think some search engines will only use the first x amount of characters on a page

Comment: @MarcB: are they allowed outside the head as per the spec? They sound promising.

Comment: @Pete seo is of no concern since this is not a public website but just a transfer of html snippets.

Comment: not really. meta tags go inside the `<head>` block. but if your system is stripping out comments, meta would be one way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This is a less than ideal situation but you can add anything inside the `doctype` tag like this:

```
<!doctype html public 'You are free to add anything here'>
```

I'm not sure how much data is allowed in there but this shouldn't mess with the parsing of the page.

Comment: Are you sure that won't mess up a parser. That string is used for supplying dtd paths: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> `

Comment: I think browsers mostly ignore it  or use it as a hint. But it still is an awful solution :)